# Behavior of the principal eigenfunction of fractional Laplacian

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

How does the first eigenfunction $\phi_{1}$ behave near the boundary of $\Omega$ where $$(-\Delta)^s\phi_{1}=\lambda_{1}\phi_{1},\text{ in } \Omega; \phi_{1} =0 \text{ in } \Omega^c$$ in a n-dimensional smooth bounded domain  with $N> 2s$ and $s\in (0, 1)$ ?

I believe that the behavior should be
$$c_{1} d(x, \partial \Omega)^s\leq \phi_{1}(x)\leq c_2 d(x, \partial \Omega)^s$$ for some $c_1>0$ and $c_2>0.$ Is this true.

Comment: If $s < 1$, then yes. This follows, for example, from *intrinsic ultracontractivity* of the corresponding semigroup. You can read more about the properties of $\phi_n$ for example in Section 2 of the 2004 [article](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jfa.2004.02.005) by R. Bañuelos and T. Kulczycki. For $s = 1$ this is a classical result. For $s > 1$ one has to impose additional boundary/exterior conditions, but I believe the standard variational approach via Sobolev spaces and quadratic forms leads to eigenfunctions with the same property.

Comment: I do not quite understand your comment, but the behaviour of $\phi_1$ is "essentially" described by the boundary Harnack inequality (and its consequences, such as existence of limits of ratios of harmonic functions); "essentially" refers to $\phi_1$ being "essentially" harmonic near the boundary.